# Got a Black screen by changing activity

Tags: java, android

i am creating a app and got a annoying bug.
When I start my second Activity my screen (on device) turns randomly black and app stucks and sometimes it changes to the 2nd activity and works fine. There are no errors ...

Please help I ve no idea how to fix that.

Comment: Try to pause in debugger and see whats going on. It probably does some work.

Comment: Please provide your code, if you want us to help.

Comment: memory leak.. try to find out where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

while creating your Intent.

Like this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```